# geometric Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

I recently read the textbook Functional analysis An introductory course by Sergei Ovchinnikov about the Geometric Hahn-Banach theorem, and he includes a lemma:
[image]

and I have a question about the blue line, my professor says that we can think as the open ball, but I doubt that this open ball is induced from the metric topology, so in general, it isn't always true, and I know that this topological vector space's topology will let the operators on vector space(+,*)be continuous only, so can anyone help me with this question, thank you very much
by the way, the \slash can just ignore.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f: r\to x+rx^*$ is continuous from $\mathbb{R}$ to $X$ (this follows from the fact that $X$ is a topological vector space so the linear and the topological structures agree). Therefore, since $f(0)=y\in V$ and $V$ is open, then $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $0$. In other words, $x+rx^*\in V$ for $r\in (-\delta,\delta)$ for sufficiently small $\delta>0$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, I recall that we can think f be the composition of the addition and scalar multiplication, so by the topological vector space definition, we get f is continuous

Comment: That's exactly right.